# jsoup | Prints blank results | I passed the Headers

Tags: jsoup

I am getting blank results | `println(doc.toString());`  // prints empty tags i.e title

`println(doc.text());`  //prints Blank results

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import java.io.IOException;

public class getText {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://www.purina.ru/";
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0");
        //Also tried full userAgent like userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36");
        Document doc = connection.get();

        System.out.println(doc.text());
        //doc.text print a Blank results
    }
}
```

Comment: When you send a `GET` request to that site, it loads JS scripts which display the site's content. `JSOUP` is no good for that.

Comment: Thank you @TDG, I will try an alternative approach